# Do I need to learn a RTOS first or can I directly go for embedded Linux?

Tags: embedded, rtos

If I wanted to learn deeply and build a embedded Linux Operating systems would i benefit from knowing about RTOS or can I straight away go for embedded Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to answer without knowing what you are planning to do. In most cases it's not helpful, sometimes even a disadvantage to be familiar with bare metal systems (with or without RTOS) for working with an embedded linux.

On the other hand, working with an RTOS gives you deeper insights to some OS principles that might be helpful to know for special tasks on n embedded linux device, like when it comes to performance optimizations or very low latency.

So let me ask back: I want to cruise on a steam boat this summer. Do I need to learn to sail first?

Comment: I want to build an embedded linux system and understand it well.

Comment: Then you will benefit more from creating your own board support package with buildroot or messing around with yocto than from dealing with an RTOS, imho.